# Finding an integration using the value of another integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

If $$ \int_0^{\infty}e^{-{x^2}} dx = \frac{{\sqrt{\pi}}}{2}$$
Then help finding 
$$ \int_0^{\infty}e^{-a{x^2}} dx$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the substitution $$x\mapsto\frac{x}{\sqrt{a}}$$
to see that (note that this substitution preserves the domain of integration)
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ax^{2}}\;dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}\;dx=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: use the substitute $u=\sqrt{a}x$.